# How to detect both TouchEvent and TapGesture in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, touch, gesture

I'm having view in Android like below and taking touch down and move event.

```
public class AndroidView : View
{
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch(e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                DownAction();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                MoveAction();
                break;

        }
        return true; // this stops parent view gestures
    }
}
```

Here i'm taking tap gesture in xamarin forms

```
 var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
            // handle the tap
        };
 view.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

My problem is

1. When i return false in ontouch event, touch move is not called
2. When i return true then tap gesture is not called.

My requirement is, i need to get both touch and tap gesture events

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Why exactly do you want both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class AndroidView : View
{
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch(e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                DownAction();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                MoveAction();
                this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;

        }
        return true; // Return true only if you want to handle touch otherwise, return base value. 
    }
}
```